# why ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION needs to location must be enabled

Tags: android, android-gps

I am trying to get user location with low battery consumption and without GPS (location). Milimetric coordinates are not necessary for me. So I decided to use

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

and also at this google developer docs https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html it says:

> Permission for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION allows access only to
>   NETWORK_PROVIDER.

I dont actually understand why this API doesn't give user current coordinates without location being enabled. In my opinion, if I use `COARSE_LOCATİON` instead of `FINE_LOCATION`, API should not use location.

I am also trying "Basic Location Sample" at https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/BasicLocationSample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are requesting for user's LOCATION it may be with FINE LOCATION or COURSE LOCATION. User needs to AUTHORIZE the app for doing that.

The only difference is that the device will spend less energy trying to get the user's location and won't get exactly location.